# FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] error with Static Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm making an app with a table view with static cells. In the storyboard, the table has labels and switches. However, when I try run the program on the simulator, I get the following errors:

```
"FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
```

and

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FirstViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance "
```

I tried implementing the following methods (even though it seems as if I don't need to since I'm using static cells):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, when I ran the app, I got a blank table.

Can anyone advise? I am pretty new to iOS programming, so any help would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks,

Jordan

**UPDATE:**

I think my problem is that I am using static cells without a UITableViewController. Is there any way I can use static cells without a UITableViewController?

Comment: You're right about not needing the table data source methods. I had trouble setting up static cells without a UITableViewController in IB. I know others say that a UITableViewController isn't necessary, but I could only get the static cells to work with one.

Comment: When you say "static cells", do you mean you've set the content type (top pull down menu for a table view) to "Static Cells" as opposed to "Dynamic Prototypes"?

Comment: if you are using static cells then why again your are  implementing the datasource methods, this way your table cell will created again. dont forget to give identifier to every cell.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the "`dataSource`" of your table view (in the XIB or Storyboard file) to point to your view controller and see if you have better luck.

Also, make sure your FirstViewController.h conforms to the "`UITableViewDataSource`" protocol.  In your .h file, it should look like this:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

The "delegate" declaration there also means your view controller can handle any delegate methods also, provided you connect the table view to your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! However, I have already made the connection. Could my problem be because my table view is "inside" of a UIView? Also, I'm not using a UITableViewController.

Comment: No, you don't need a UITableViewController.  Set a breakpoint right inside your "`numberOfRowsInSection:`" method and see if it stops there when your view displays.